# Combing xml and java configuration for spring/hibernate datasource as AWS RDS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Trying to connect my spring/hibernate project which is running locally on my machine to my aws rds.I am trying to modify my previous setup which was a h2 local database datasource. Unsure how to combine the xml and java config to import the bean into the java config?

My dataconfig.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

<aws-context:context-region region="eu-west-1a"/>
<aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="
   my key" secret-key="my key" />
</aws-context:context-credentials>
<jdbc:data-source
        db-instance-identifier="mydb"
        password="my password">
</jdbc:data-source>
```

Dataconfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "haughton.icecreamapi.dao")
public class DataConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;




@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entity.package"));
    factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return factory;
}


private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",env.getProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    //removed to keep db consistent
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

    // Driver class name
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));

    // Set URL
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));

    // Set username & password
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));

    return ds;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the reason to keep xml configuration?

Comment: According to the spring cloud AWS documentatiom RDS can only be configured via xml

Answer (score 0):

### SPRING CLOUD / AWS

The [Spring Cloud doc Section 3.1.2](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) tells you how to move your XML config into annotations. It says to add some annotations to your Application Configuration object. (Create a new one if you don't have one yet.)

```
@Configuration
@EnableContextInstanceData
public static class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

You have some options for specifying your keys:

- use the environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- use the system properties aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
- use the user specific profile credentials file. To do this, just run `aws configure` from whatever user is running your application and set the keys and region there. If you go this route, remember to do this in production as part of your system setup.
- use the instance profile credentials (you aren't running on an EC2 instance, so this won't work for you)

I recommend going with the 3rd bullet point option.

You may also be able to wire up the values from your application.properties file, but I don't know how to do that.

### DATA SOURCE

Source: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/

@Configuration
class PersistenceContext {

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}

//Add the other beans here
```

}

This example uses the Hikari connection pooling framework. IF you want to use that, you'll have to add the appropriate dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

That requires Java 7; there are other compatibility versions available for Java 6-9. Of course, you can use different connection pool if you wish.